# Datatable values to datagridview, only showing one columns data

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have a datatable filled with a report from a web service. I am now trying to display the datatable in an datagridview. This is the code I use to build the datatable:

```
// Create DataTabe to handle the output
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Clear();
dt.Columns.Add("EmployeeFirstName");
dt.Columns.Add("EmployeeLastName");
dt.Columns.Add("DepartmentName");
dt.Columns.Add("DepartmentCode");
dt.Columns.Add("LocationName");
dt.Columns.Add("DivisionCode");
dt.Columns.Add("EarningName");
dt.Columns.Add("OTHours");
dt.Columns.Add("WorkDate")
```

Fill the new datatable:

```
foreach (ReportRow row in report.Rows)
{
  dt.Rows.Add(string.Join(",", row.ColumnValues));
}
```

Then I try to bind the data in the datatable to the dataGridview:

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

When I run the application it only displays the data from the first column in the datatable. Do I need a loop of sorts to work through the columns or am I just missing a step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after sleeping I have found the issue with dropping it into an sql table... I didn't take into account that the export to a CSV and the addition of the " , " would affect the export to sql. Here is the modification of the lines of code that was the issue:

```
  foreach (ReportRow row in report.Rows)
  {
      dt.Rows.Add(row.ColumnValues);
  }
```

Thank you all for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's cause you are adding only one value to your `dt` when you say `dt.Rows.Add(string.Join(",", row.ColumnValues));`. You should be doing something like below (assuming that `ReportRow` also has the columns with same names like `"EmployeeFirstName"` else change the names accordingly)

```
foreach (ReportRow row in report.Rows)
{
  DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
  dr["EmployeeFirstName"] = row["EmployeeFirstName"];
  dr["EmployeeLastName"] = row["EmployeeLastName"];
  dr["DepartmentName"] = row["DepartmentName"];
  //rest of the columns fill

//once all columns filled
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Comment: I have attempted to do this in an earlier revision but came up with the following error:

Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'ReportCollector.ReportService.ReportRow'

Also, when I export dt to a csv file I see all the data I need in the dataGridView with the code I originally posted. I might be handling this all wrong to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

`dt.Rows.Add(string.Join(",", row.ColumnValues));` -> You can either add a single `DataRow` item or a array of objects.

From your call, you chose the later, you are adding a array of objects, except you are adding ONE SINGLE object.

`string.Join(",", row.ColumnValues)` is one object.